# How to remove last line space streamwriter?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0, c#-2.0

currently i'm facing issue while creating file, i'm trying to write text contents using streamWriter class but i'm not getting expected answer..
Below is my example code :-

My c# code looks like :-

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        // Create a connexion to the Remote Server to redirect all requests
        RemoteServer server = new RemoteServer(context);

        // Create a request with same data in navigator request
        HttpWebRequest request = server.GetRequest();

        // Send the request to the remote server and return the response
        HttpWebResponse response = server.GetResponse(request);
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=playlist.m3u8");
        context.Response.ContentType = response.ContentType;

        Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        var buff = new byte[1024];
        int bytes = 0;
        string token = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        while ((bytes = receiveStream.Read(buff, 0, 1024)) > 0)
        {
            //Write the stream directly to the client 
            context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buff, 0, bytes);

            context.Response.Write("&token="+token);
        }
        //close streams
        response.Close();
        context.Response.End();
    }
```

output of above code looks like :-

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=20776,CODECS="avc1.66.41",RESOLUTION=320x240
chunk.m3u8?nimblesessionid=62
&token=42712adc-f932-43c7-b282-69cf349941da
```

But my expected output is :-

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:3
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=20776,CODECS="avc1.66.41",RESOLUTION=320x240
chunk.m3u8?nimblesessionid=62&token=42712adc-f932-43c7-b282-69cf349941da
```

I just wanted that token param in same line instead of new line..

Thank you.

Comment: Have you checked that the data you receive from the server does not already end with a newline? If so, you would need to filter it out before writing to `context.Response`.

Comment: @jcb I'm getting data in bytes, so how can i filter that before writing it into file ?
Can you give me an example code ?

Comment: You could do something like `if (buff[bytes-1] == 0x0a) bytes -= 1;`, this would check if the newline byte ('\n' if a character, 0x0a is the hex value) is the last byte you received, and then acts as if you received one byte less. However, depending on your server, you might receive a carriage return byte ('\r' or 0x0d), or even both as the end of your message. Adapt as necessary :)

Comment: @jcb sorry i'm not expert in streamWriter part, so can you please explain how could i do that ? :)

Comment: No direct relation with the issue, but if I understand what you're trying to do then the `context.Response.Write("&token="+token);` line should be outside of the `while` loop

Comment: As for the question itself, if performance isn't an issue then you should read the whole content of the request into a string, modify at your convenience (one of the advantage is that you can then use `yourString.TrimEnd('\n')`), and write the new string to the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to simply remove a newline at the end of the received bytes, change the code in your `while` loop like so:

```
while ((bytes = receiveStream.Read(buff, 0, 1024)) > 0)
{
    if (buff[bytes-1] == 0x0a)
        bytes -= 1;

    //Write the stream directly to the client 
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buff, 0, bytes);

    context.Response.Write("&token="+token);
}
```

Several caveats:

- It will only work if `0x0a` (newline byte, `'\n'` as a character) is at the end of the bytes you *received*. If for some reason the message sent by the server is received in several blocks, you will first have to make sure you received everything there is to receive before checking the last byte.
  Please also note that this would result in multiple `&token=...` lines in your current code.
- Depending on the server, it might use carriage return (`0x0d` or `'\r'`) as its line ending byte, or even both. Check what the server sends and adapt the code accordingly.

Comment: I believe this may get slightly more complicated than that, because OP probably doesn't actually want to write the token every 1024 bytes... Though it definitely answers the question in its current form

Comment: @kevin-gosse: Yes, hence my comment to that effect :) You are right, this is strictly answering the question as asked, not really adressing all possible problems. I was not sure how far to go there, in regards to SO practices etc.

Comment: @kevin i think we need to write that token code outside of while loop